# Equals and HashCode for a class that has a dictionary<t,k> as an attribute

Tags: c#, dictionary

As you would know the `Dictionary` class in C# does not override `Equals` and `hashCode`. I am facing a scenario where I have a class that has an attribute `Dictionary<T,K>`. I have generated the hash code and equals for this class using the standard VS snippets. As a result when `.Equals()` is invoked on an instance of this class, for the dictionary attribute, `.Equals()` of object gets invoked and I always get a false result.

Attached is a sample dummy class for clarification.

```
public class TestClass : IEquatable<TestClass>
{
    private string _dummyName;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _dummyDict;

    public bool Equals(TestClass other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Equals(other._dummyName, _dummyName) && Equals(other._dummyDict, _dummyDict);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (TestClass)) return false;
        return Equals((TestClass) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((_dummyName != null ? _dummyName.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (_dummyDict != null ? _dummyDict.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Dictionary does not override Equals, so for the dictionary attribute, Equals from object class will get invoked giving incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

```
return Equals(other._dummyName, _dummyName) && Equals(other._dummyDict, _dummyDict);
```

which will call your `Equals` implementation. This implementation returns `false` for all objects that are not of type `TestClass` as long as they're not reference equal.

Your first call hasr strings as parameter, your second call Dictionary. Both qould return false.